# can I allocate memory for all YARN container by percentage

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I use ambari to manage yarn cluster,

[image: allocate max memory available]

I can only allocate memory for yarn on every node by seting its max value like 12G;

I want to allocate memory for yarn by percentage,because these nodes have different memery:l6G,32G,so the cluster can use more memory.

Comment: Not directly, but maybe try to use host configuration groups?

Comment: I do not think it is possible behaivor.  I am not sure why you have differences but your worker nodes should all remain the same spec.